# Not able to move a partition to resize the root partition on ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I was following this video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yOOcg5Cm4DM. The video used  EaseUS partition master but that didn't help because I can't move the unallocated space below the EXT4 file system partition on my PC. Only after the unallocated space is below the EXT4 partition I can increase its size. I also don't know what this 25.54GB partition is. Can anyone help me increase the partition size of Ubuntu?

I am using Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I have a bootable USB drive ready but I am stuck on this problem. I have attached a screenshot of my PC's disk partition.[disk partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdHd1.png)

Edit1- I tried a different approach. First shrank C drive by 10GB then expanded the root space for Ubuntu to use that unallocated space.

Comment: Never use Windows tools to manage Linux partitions.  You'll need unpartitioned free space in the partition *after* the one you want to expand.  There's not enough information to identify the partition you are talking about. What would it have to do with Ubuntu? What are its contents?

Comment: @Nmath Hi, thanks for your comment. Did you see the image I attached with the question? The highlighted partition is the one I don't know what that is. I want to combine the partition above and below that highlighted partition. The unallocated one is from the E drive of windows and almost occupied one above is root partition of Ubuntu

Comment: Yes I reviewed your whole question before responding.  The unallocated partition is unallocated space. It is definitely not part of Window's "E" partition.  The screenshot of your application tells us very little about the highlighted partition. It does not tell us the file system, contents, where it came from, or what it's for. I can tell you that doesn't look like it has anything to do with Ubuntu, so I'm not sure if we can help identify your partition for you.  At the very least, you should be using Linux partitioning tools, like "Disks" or gparted in Ubuntu.

Comment: Trying to use Windows to work on your Ubuntu partitions is a bad idea and can result in destruction of your Ubuntu filesystem. Windows does not know how to work with the file systems that Ubuntu uses, nor does it know how to handle POSIX ownership and permissions